# How can I make Search Terms in a View to look fo into the edited Summary?

Tags: views, search

I have a View of a type of content, and it has a Search Terms contextual filter. It searches perfectly (after indexing the content and running cron), but when I have a node which has the summary edited (not the default trimmed body text), the search does not return any result. How can I include the edited version of the Summary in the search?

Comment: good question. if it was an exposed filter I would say use a `global combined filter` for summary field and body. but, since you want a contextual filter -- goodluck.

Comment: How are you indexing your content?

Comment: I have included search in the Manage Display --> Search indexing. But the Safe Summary is not included in the list, just the Content body. I cannot believe the version 7 of Drupal does not include this search by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how to get it work: just selecting in the Manage Display --> Search Indexing, Body Summary or trimmed. Isn't it confussing? It seems that it will search only in the summary, while it searches in both Summary and Body. And now it works with edited Summaries.